# unexpected token "{" using if statement

Tags: javascript

I don't know why but I keep getting this syntax error of Unexpected Token "{" on the initial if statement every time I run this snippet. Any idea why?

```
var place = prompt("Go ahead and pick a place, it could be anywhere.");

if ((!isNaN(place)) {
    place = prompt("That doesn\'t sound like a place. Try again. Pick a place", "");
} else if (place == "" || place == null) {
    place = alert("You\'re no fun. Come back when you want an adventure");
} else {
    place = alert("So out of all the places you picked, you picked " + place + "?");
}
```

Comment: `if ((!isNaN(place))` it should be `if (!isNaN(place))`. Brackets are not balanced.

Comment: I see my mistake now. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is because you need one more closing ')'. This:

```
if ((!isNaN(place))
```

should be

```
if ((!isNaN(place))) { //one for isNaN, one for (!..) and one more for if()
```

Comment: @Ankit true. Ideally he could just write if(!isNaN(place)).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.